# How to delete table from sqlite database over ssh debian

Tags: sqlite, google-cloud-platform

Hi friends can you please help. I turned on 2 way authentication on isp manager root user and lost phone. So i need to delete table using ssh 'totp' from sqlite database /usr/local/mgr5/etc/ispmgr.db.

Can you please suggest command i need to run? I searched forums but did not find any answer. I managed to browse files and open it with nano command but it is not a way.

I use google cloud with debian 8

Comment: I updated my answer hopefully its clearer now.

Comment: Thanks with your help i solved that.

Comment: cool, glad you got it solved

Answer (score 0):

once you're logged into your remote machine, using your ssh shell, `cd` into the directory with the sqlite database file and first check your connection with the DB:

```
% sqlite3 << 'EOF' drop_table.db
.fullschema
EOF
```

If everything is ok this might produce output like

```
CREATE TABLE dropme(
id integer primary key autoincrement,
description text);
/* No STAT tables available */
```

Then try running your drop table command

```
% sqlite3 << 'EOF' drop_table.db
drop table dropme;
EOF
```

obviously you need to substitute your database file and table into the command

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. It writtes bash: fg: %: no such job. I think i need replace . I think i am wrong adding table name. % sqlite3 << 'EOF' ispmgr.db
.fullschema
EOF
CREATE TABLE totp(
id integer primary key autoincrement,
description text);
/* No STAT tables available */

Comment: @IgorsMaslakovs don't enter the `%`. thats a command prompt to indicate the command should be run from a terminal

Comment: shoud it be this way ? sqlite3 << 'EOF' ispmgr.db
drop table totp;
EOF

Comment: sory i am comlite noob

Comment: no, its using a heredoc so you need the new lines, just copy paste my command into your terminal - without the `%`

Comment: Could you please writte how command should look if table is called totp and db is ispmgr.db

Comment: root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc# CREATE TABLE dropme(
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc# id integer primary key autoincrement,
id: extra operand ‘primary’
Try 'id --help' for more information.
root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc# description text);
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc# /* No STAT tables available */
bash: /bin: Is a directory
root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc# % sqlite3 << 'EOF' drop_table.db
> drop table dropme;
> EOF
bash: fg: %: no such job
root@meko1:/usr/local/mgr5/etc#

Comment: what i do worong?